# How to install OpenGL version 2.0

Tags: installation, sudo, opengl

How can I install OpenGL 2.0 on Ubuntu?

Long Version: This Ububtu is running in a VM (VMWare). I wanted to use [kivy](http://kivy.org) for developing a GUI.

I encountered many errors. I have searched around and those errors are gone.
Now I get

> Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!

error.

I have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python-opengl
sudo apt-get install python-gst0.10
sudo apt-get install python-enchant
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
sudo apt-get install cython
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev

sudo pip install kivy
```

And kivy is installed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hardware/driver need to support the required OpenGL version, you can check the version reported using

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

As you are using a VM, you should check it supports GPU acceleration, and if ubuntu detects it correctly.

Comment: My VM does not starts now :\ but before that it said the version is 1.4. I'll try again. Thanks;